# What do the new Terms and Conditions for the iTunes Store mean?

Tags: ipad, itunes

In the new Terms and Conditions for the iTunes store, it says that the following has changed:

> Notification of an additional type of previously purchased content
>   that may be subsequently downloaded to certain computers and devices
>   as an accommodation to you, subject to existing association rules; and
>   that such content may be played back on certain devices that are not
>   subject to existing association rules, with limitations.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you can download TV shows you've purchased in the past for different Apple devices, though it may not always be available to download at all times.

[Source](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/08/01/apple-brings-tv-to-icloud-with-downloads-of-previously-purchased-episodes/)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take your word for it.  Some day, when I have no job and no life, I'll read the forty pages or so of legalese in the agreement, and find out what it actually says in there. :P

Comment: "Some day, when I have no job and no life, I'll read the forty pages". Then you will also lose your sanity ;-)